# Can I specify a schedule job using PHP?

Tags: php, windows, xampp

Actually I saw there are some related question but I am not sure whether they fits me because I am using the latest version of XAMPP on Windows 7

So, simply speaking, on Windows I have a script (eg. `sendEmail.php`) is for me to mend mail, so how can I call it after 5 minutes for me to send, for instance?

And if send a email depend on some variable (e.g. userID) can I specify one in the cron job?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just created a scheduled task to run this:

```
php.exe sendEmail.php your command line args here
```

You can then access those arguments via `$argv`.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: actually what i would like to achieve is first the user input the time, and some processing in server, then it will execute for a certain time once the server is running

Comment: @LeoChan, Typically for this sort of thing, you will schedule what needs to happen in a database.  Your script will run every few minutes or so, and check the database.  If there are e-mails ready to send, it sends them and marks them as sent in the table.